# How can I understand if I am reading the last line of a file in bash?

Tags: bash, readfile, line-by-line

I would like to read a file line by line, edit the line and put it into a new file:

```
while read my_line
do
    # doesn't handle the last OR
    printf "'%s'\$label OR " $my_line >> delivered 
done < "labels.txt"
```

Unfortunately, by following this approach, I add a OR also after the last element of my file.

I thought that in some way I could handle this case by identifying the last line: from the man page, when $? for read is different from 0, then we have the end-of-file; but in this case I can't use it inside the loop to create a different printf instruction.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: How about printing the OR before whatever else you want to print, if it's not the first line?

Comment: it is an alternative approach... How could I handle the first line?

Comment: Err... with a boolean variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another funny solution, using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ cat file.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
$ perl -pe 's/.*/\047$&\047/; !eof && s/\n/\$label OR /g' file.txt
'aaa'$label OR 'bbb'$label OR 'ccc'
```

This have the advantage to have a very clear syntax, isn't it ?

- `-pe` stands for `print` by default (like `sed`) & assuming `while (<>) {}` equivalent
- `\047` stands for octal representation of single quote `'`
- `!eof` stands for `if the EOF is not reached`
- `s///` is the basic skeleton for a *sed like* substitution

Comment: Thank you, I think this is my favourite solution, I will adopt it! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
while read my_line
do
  printf "'%s'"
  read -t 0 && printf " OR "
done < "labels.txt" > delivered
```

The second `read` (specifying a timeout of 0 seconds with `-t`) succeeds only if there is input available, but does not consume any input. After you have printed the last line, it will *not* succeed, and so you won't print the trailing "OR".

Comment: I just checked; it appears this feature of the `-t` flag was introduced in the 4 series of `bash` (not documented in `bash` 3.2, but is in the man page for 4.1).

Answer (score 1):

The classic workaround for this is to just append a line with `0=1`. making it `'FOO' OR 'BAR' OR 0=1`:

```
{
while read my_line
do
    # doesn't handle the last OR
    printf "'%s'\$label OR " $my_line
done 
echo 0=1
} < "labels.txt" > delivered
```

This has the additional benefit of turning an empty input file into the valid expression `0=1` rather than the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with `head` and `tail` :

```
$ cat test.txt
aa
bb
cc
dd
$ head -n -1 test.txt|sed "s/$/ OR/"; tail -n 1 test.txt
aa OR
bb OR
cc OR
dd
```

`head` reads the file except the last line, as meant by the `-1` for number of lines. Then `sed` adds the keyword at the end of each line, which is matched by `$` in the search expression. Then tail adds the last line unmodified.

As there are two commands, to redirect the output to a file, you can run it in a subshell :

```
$ (head -n -1 test.txt|sed "s/$/ OR/"; tail -n 1 test.txt) > output
```